# Automatically turn on enriched mode and make newlines between paragraphs hard in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I want to turn on enriched-mode in Emacs by default, so that my `*scratch*` buffer would always open in that mode. I've got my `*scratch*` persistent across sessions (http://dorophone.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-make-emacs-scratch-buffer.html).

I added `(enriched-mode)` to my `.emacs` file, but then every start up I need to answer the question:
`Make newlines between paragraphs hard? (y or n)`. I tried to add `(use-hard-newlines)` before or after `(enriched-mode)`, to add `'yes`, `1` and others to both commands, but it doesn't work. `C-h f enriched-mode` shows no answer.

Comment: **User Option**: `initial-major-mode` -- *The value of this variable determines the major mode of the initial `*scratch*` buffer. The value should be a symbol that is a major mode command. The default value is `lisp-interaction-mode`.*  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Auto-Major-Mode.html  In other words, add this to your `.emacs` file and remove the other stuff you tried:  `(setq initial-major-mode 'enriched-mode)`  Then, restart Emacs.

Comment: @lawlist: `enriched-mode` is a **minor** mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it today. First of all the loading of autosaved scratch file was done by shell's `cat` function and was to be replaced with `insert-file`. Then `(enriched-mode)` had to be added to the loading script. Once the scratch was edited as rich text (`M-x enriched-mode` and answering the hard-lines prompt) it will open in enrichment mode without prompting.

Here's my function:

```
(defun load-persistent-scratch ()
  "Load the contents of PERSISTENT-SCRATCH-FILENAME into the
  scratch buffer, clearing its contents first."
  (if (file-exists-p persistent-scratch-filename)
      (with-current-buffer (get-buffer "*scratch*")
        (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
        (insert-file persistent-scratch-filename)))
  (enriched-mode))
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points that might help:

1. Neither `enriched-mode` nor `use-hard-newlines` is a global minor mode; they are both local to the current buffer. So turning them on in your init file the way you are doing just turns them on for whatever buffer was current at the time your init file was being read.

   You need to have them turned on automatically in whatever modes you want (maybe all modes).  Buffer `*scratch*` is in `lisp-interaction-mode`.  Generally, however, enriched text is used for `text-mode` and its derivatives (and typically not for modes where font-lock highlighting is used).
2. You need to use `(use-hard-newlines 1 'always)`.  The `always` prevents being prompted and always replaces the newlines.